# Detect SQL Server 2008 R2 from WIX

Tags: sql-server-2008, wix

**SQL Server 2008 R2** is one of my installer prerequisites.  I know we need to check the registry entry using **RegistrySearch** to detect the SQL Server. I have searched through web, but I am totally confused about lot of registry entries. I have checked on my own in SQL Server 2008 R2 installed machine and found below registry entries. Could anyone please let me know which one is correct entry to check? Is there any other standard registry entry to detect SQL servers?

CurrentVersion value is 10.5

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Redist\SQLBrowser\1033\CurrentVersion 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Redist\SQLBrowser\CurrentVersion

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Redist\SQLNCLI10\1033\CurrentVersion

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\ClientSetup\CurrentVersion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently I do the following searches to check what is installed. The first two tell me that SqlServer is installed at any version. The second two tell me whether it is Sql 2008R2. I can then use these to make a decision whether to do a fresh install or upgrade an existing instance (I haven't tested whether this works with Sql2012 installed, I doubt that it will work as I don't expect you can "upgrade" Sql2012 to Sql2008R2):

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSSQL$[SqlInstance]"
                     Result="exists"
                     Variable="SQLServerInstalled" />

<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\MSSQLSERVER"
                     Result="exists"
                     Variable="DefaultSQLServerInstalled" />

<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.[SqlInstance]"
                     Result="exists"
                     Variable="SQLServer2008R2Installed" />

<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER"
                     Result="exists"
                     Variable="DefaultSQLServer2008R2Installed" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @caveman_dick. How to get the SqlInstance, if multiple SQL Server instances are installed.

Comment: That's what I found difficult. There is a registry entry that lists the instances, but Wix 3.6 cannot import a REG_MULTI which is what they are stored in. Not sure if this has been fixed in 3.7 though.

Comment: I am using C# Custom Action and Complete this. Now it is working fine. Thanks once again.